# Fungible tokens owned by non-fungible tokens

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I'm quite a Noob when it comes to smart contracts, and I'm trying to design a market place.

I will tokenise existing real world assets into ERC 721 tokens. The owner of each ERC721 will be eligible to mint x-amount of ERC-20 tokens, depending on it's unique characteristics.

Does that sound sensible, or does any part of that sound unreasonable?

It might make sense for the 721 to own the erc-20s initially - is that possible, does it have to be the owner of the 721, or is there a better way?

Are there similar use-cases out there already that I can look at?

Comment: Maybe you're interested in [ERC-1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155), which is basically a combination of ERC-20 and ERC-721.

Comment: Thanks @Morten - yeah that's on my radar :)

Answer (score 0):

While there are specific implementations of 1155 trying to be retrocompatible with 721,
It sounds to me like the [ERC998](http://erc998.org/) is what you are looking for. A composable token using erc721 and therefore compatible with it. It allows for erc721 to own erc20 tokens.